# Using .htaccess to clean a URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've looked around, and most things either seem overkill, or I'm just not understanding something.

I've got the following URLs:

```
http://cms.dev/article.php?post_id=6
```

And I like to replace them with

```
http://cms.dev/article/6/
```

I've got the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

However, this just cleans URLs like `/admin.php` to `/admin`.

What is the best way to clean a URL, but keep the .php removed from other pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /$1.php?post_id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)$ article.php?post_id=$1
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/$ article.php?post_id=$1
```

Source: [10 Simple examples to rewrite using htaccess](http://www.myaakriti.com/web/htaccess/10-useful-ways-to-rewrite-url-using-htaccess/)

Comment: Thanks. How come the rewrite rule is written twice?

Comment: For both `http://cms.dev/article/6/` and `http://cms.dev/article/6`. i.e. with or without backslash at end

Comment: You can do `^article/([0-9]+)/?$ article.php?post_id=$1` to condense it to a single line. The "?" means that the last "/" is optional.